# chage - Minimum number of days between password change

Tags: linux, password

is there any difference in the "Minimum number of days between password change" set to `-1` and `0`?

or maybe both commas does the same policy?

```
chage -m -1 user
chage -m 0 user
```

thank you for any hint, I can't find -1 descirbed in chage manual but it is possible to set it to `-1`

```
Minimum number of days between password change          : -1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the source for `chage` there's a comment that explains what `-1` does:

```
/*
 * new_fields - change the user's password aging information interactively.
 *
 * prompt the user for all of the password age values. set the fields
 * from the user's response, or leave alone if nothing was entered. The
 * value (-1) is used to indicate the field should be removed if possible.
 * any other negative value is an error. very large positive values will
 * be handled elsewhere.
 */
```

So when you specify `chage -m -1 <user>` it's disabling the mindays field. So disabling it with a `-1` vs. setting it to 0 would appear to have the same effect, when it comes to restricting the how frequently a user can change their password.

#### References

- [github repo - shadow/src/chage.c](https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow/blob/master/src/chage.c#L179)